# Is there any algorithm which can take care of other conditions as well along with finding shortest path?

Tags: google-maps, graph-theory, combinatorics, shortest-path, a-star

Similar to what google maps does ?
Find shortest path but consider road utilization (traffic congestion) as a factor

Road Utilization - if the current shortest road has x(pre-defined) limit reached - then use another path (might not be shortest)

Is there a algorithm like this ? Possibly deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Normal path-finding algorithms such as A* can already do this. The trick is to include the road utilization in the edge weights. For example, you could consider the edge-weights to be the "estimated time to drive between two nodes", rather than the physical distance.

Comment: I give it a shot !